# jquery Checkbox live click event jams firefox when actually clicking the checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click, live

I have the following jquery code specified:

```
$('#firstbox ul.checkboxlist input[type="checkbox"]').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parents('li').remove().clone().prependTo('#secondbox ul.checkboxlist').animate({backgroundColor: '#FAEA96'},100, function(){$(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'},800);});
});
```

It takes the li, removes it, and puts it into a second box when you click the checkbox. Works fine in IE. Also it works fine if I click the text on the label. However if I directly click the checkbox on firefox, firefox slows right down for about 10/15 seconds and logs these errors:

> Warning: Expected number or percentage in rgb() but found 'NaN'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped.
>   Line: 0

Firebug returns Too much recursion.

Why is it different if I click the label to when I click the actual checkbox?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `.parent('li')` instead of `.parents('li')`

Comment: It's not a direct parent, it needs to look through multiple parents to find the li :)

Comment: You might want to try closest('li') to get the first li if the lists are nested.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery UI? If you want to animate the background color you need to use at least the core effects.  Also, have you tried it without using the clone()?  Since you are removing the elements from the previous list, you shouldn't need to clone them.  You might also try using the [highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight)() effect -- that seems to be be what you are doing.

None of these addresses your exact question of why FF seems to handle it differently, but hopefully one of them will resolve the issue.

Comment: I'm not using UI, I have included the jquery color plugin to allow .animate to work with colours. It works a treat other than when clicking the checkbox.

Comment: Have you thought about simply getting the core and effects pieces of jQuery UI and seeing if that solves your problem?  I don't know anything about the color plugin, but the UI code is extensively used and may be more robust.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery documentation for the method "remove" does not need this method if you are using course "appendTo" or other method.
Which I would rather not need to use "clone", in my opinion the code could be this way, and at some point I had problems with double quotes and single quotes (`"input[type='checkbox']"`) for that reason I use the quotes in this way.

[info for remove()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove)

```
$("#firstbox ul.checkboxlist").find("input[type='checkbox']").live("click",function(){

    $(this)
        .parents("li")
        .prependTo("#secondbox ul.checkboxlist")
        .animate({backgroundColor: "#FAEA96"},100, function(){
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 800);
        });

});
```

EDIT:
for remove event click

```
$("#firstbox ul.checkboxlist").find("input[type='checkbox']").live("click",function myEventClick(){

    $(this)
        .unbind("click", myEventClick)
        .parents("li")
        .prependTo("#secondbox ul.checkboxlist")
        .animate({backgroundColor: "#FAEA96"},100, function(){
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 800);
        });

});
```

Comment: You might want to use remove() **if** you wanted to make sure that any event handlers are also removed.  Using only prependTo() will result in the handlers being retained.  In this case it may be a moot point since the only handler we know about is the live handler which is on the document, not the elements themselves.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll play around with this. I've actually decided to 'hide' the checkboxes so they won't even be able to be clicked. Still, if I can make the remove stuff better.